# Laravel get database results from user's form input details

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I've been searching for a solution to a query I'm trying to run.
I have a database table called locations and I need the user to be able to submit a form to change/filter the results that are returned.

The 2 fields the user can select are charity & distance 
the fields aren't mandatory so it'll need to check if they are set.

I currently have it working with distance but can't get it to work when both are filled in using AND WHERE

here's my controller function

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $circle_radius = 3959;
        $max_distance = $request->Input(['distance']);
        $charity = $request->Input(['charities']);
        $lat = '53.5526';
        $lng = '-1.479726';

        $locations = DB::select(
            'SELECT * FROM
                (SELECT *, (' . $circle_radius . ' * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
                cos(radians(longitude) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
                sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(latitude))))
                AS distance
                FROM locations) AS distances
            WHERE distance < ' . $max_distance . '
            AND charity = ' . $charity . '
            ORDER BY distance;
            ');

        return view('map.search', compact('locations'));

    }
```

If I take the AND charity line out it works with just distance but I need both

Comment: Does it work with only charity and not distance?  Log the query and the run it manually?  maybe $charity doesn't have the exact matching value.  Also, doing it they way you are is very dangerous, putting it at risk for SQL injection

Comment: Have you considered using Laravel query builder to simplify/debug this? I suggest breaking this query down and determining if it's a SQL problem or a php variable issue.

Comment: Also, should it not be $request->input('whatever') rather than $request->Input(['whatever']) ?

Comment: Yeah it works with just the charity. 
I tried to use the query builder but couldn't get the distance working with that so tried this way just to see if the query was right.

Answer (score 0):

Got my query working by doing the following. If anyone knows a better solution that would be good.

```
$max_distance = $request->input('distance');
        $charity = $request->input('charities');
        $lat = '53.5526';
        $lng = '-1.479726';

        $locations = Location::select('locations.*')
                    ->selectRaw('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                                       cos( radians( latitude ) )
                                       * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
                                       ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                                       sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                                     ) AS distance', [$lat, $lng, $lat])
                    ->havingRaw("distance < ?", [$max_distance])
                    ->where('charity', '=', $charity)
                    ->get();
```